# Get-WebBinding - Class Alternative

Tags: powershell

I'm having an issue using `Get-Website` and `Get-WebBinding` inside a workflow.

```
Get-Website -Name 'Default Web Site'
```

Returns the exception: `Get-Website : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

A solution is to use: `Get-ChildItem "iis:\sites"`.

My question: is there an alternative way to return the properties of `Get-WebBinding` and bypass this exception? Or does someone know how to fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: Try with `InlineScript` inside the workflow : `InlineScript { Get-Website -Name 'Default Web Site' }`

Comment: **[About InlineScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_inlinescript?view=powershell-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-PSWorkflow)** : _The InlineScript activity runs commands in a shared Windows PowerShell session. You can include it in a workflow to run commands that share data and commands that are not otherwise valid in a workflow._. Maybe it could help but I cannot test.

Comment: @Manu It worked - thanks. If you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks, I just posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `InlineScript` inside the workflow :

```
InlineScript { Get-Website -Name 'Default Web Site' }
```

**[About InlineScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_inlinescript?view=powershell-5.1) :**

*"The InlineScript activity runs commands in a shared Windows PowerShell session. You can include it in a workflow to run commands that share data and commands that are not otherwise valid in a workflow."*